# Append argument to arguments list

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, arguments

I have the following Bash code:

```
function suman {

    if test "$#" -eq "0"; then
        echo " [suman] using suman-shell instead of suman executable.";
        suman-shell "$@"
    else
        echo "we do something else here"
    fi

}


function suman-shell {

    if [ -z "$LOCAL_SUMAN" ]; then
        local -a node_exec_args=( )
        handle_global_suman node_exec_args "$@"
    else
        NODE_PATH="${NEW_NODE_PATH}" PATH="${NEW_PATH}" node "$LOCAL_SUMAN" --suman-shell "$@";
    fi
}
```

when the `suman` command is executed by the user with no arguments, then this is hit:

```
  echo " [suman] using suman-shell instead of suman executable.";
  suman-shell "$@"
```

my question is - how can I append an argument to the "$@" value?
I need to simply do something like:

```
handle_global_suman node_exec_args "--suman-shell $@"
```

obviously that's wrong but I cannot figure out how to do it. What I am *not* looking for -

```
handle_global_suman node_exec_args "$@" --suman-shell
```

the problem is that `handle_global_suman` works with `$1` and `$2` and if I make `--suman-shell` into `$3`, then I have to change other code, and would rather avoid that.

*Preliminary answer:*

```
    local args=("$@")
    args+=("--suman-shell")

    if [ -z "$LOCAL_SUMAN" ]; then
        echo " => No local Suman executable could be found, given the present working directory => $PWD"
        echo " => Warning...attempting to run a globally installed version of Suman..."
        local -a node_exec_args=( )
        handle_global_suman node_exec_args "${args[@]}"
    else
        NODE_PATH="${NEW_NODE_PATH}" PATH="${NEW_PATH}" node "$LOCAL_SUMAN" "${args[@]}";
    fi
```

Comment: I think this question could really be pared down and genericized quite a bit, i.e. I think it would be better if there were a more minimal example illustrating the main point of the question.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams seems to have answered it, but I will try to clean up the question

Comment: Cool. Another small comment: I was actually going to post the same solution as ignacio-vazquez-abrams, but it seemed to me that hauke-laging had also answered it. I think focusing on the subcommand invocation distracted a little bit from the fact that you really wanted the result stored in a variable and not just passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the arguments into an array and then append to the array.

```
args=("$@")
args+=(foo)
args+=(bar)
baz "${args[@]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to resort to an array - you can manipulate the arguments themselves by using `set --`:

```
$ manipulateArgs() {
  set -- 'my prefix' "$@" 'my suffix'
  for i in "$@"; do echo "$i"; done
}

$ manipulateArgs 'the middle'
my prefix
the middle
my suffix
```

Answer (score 1):

```
handle_global_suman node_exec_args --suman-shell "$@"
```

Comment: thanks, but look at the last thing I said in the question

Comment: I have a variable number of arguments, I'd like to concatenate them all into `"$@"`, if you will, before passing them to another function.

Comment: @AlexanderMills At which position shall `--suman-shell` be?

Comment: the position doesn't matter in this case

Comment: I created a "preliminary answer" in the OP, at the very bottom