# How to append arguments in a ZSH loop and then pass them to a command?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, arguments, mkv, mkvtoolnix

Using `mkvmerge`, I want to add audio tracks to several MKV clips that are arranged like this

```
Clips_folder
/spa/clip1.mka
/spa/clip2.mka
/ger/clip1.mka
/ger/clip2.mka
/clip1.mkv
/clip2.mkv
```

That's the script I have ([based on 'Append argument to arguments list'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402700/append-argument-to-arguments-list)):

```
#!/bin/zsh

mkdir -p output

for video in *.mkv
do
    audioargs=("-o ./output/${video} --language 0:eng ${video}")
    for audiodir in *(/)
        do
            audioargs+=("--language 0:${audiodir} ./${audiodir}/${video:r}.mka")
        done
    echo ${audioargs[@]}
done
```

That's the output:

```
-o ./output/clip1.mkv --language 0:eng clip1.mkv --language 0:spa ./spa/clip1.mka --language 0:ger ./ger/clip1.mka
```

But when I change it to `mkvmerge ${audioargs[@]}` I get

```
mkvmerge v45.0.0 ('Heaven in Pennies') 64-bit
Error: no destination file name was given
```

How do I correctly pass `audioargs` to `mkvmerge` so that it's expanded to `mkvmerge -o file --language ...` etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have `mkvmerge` to test with, but I'm pretty sure the problem is how you quote things when you build the array. When you do something like

```
audioargs=("-o ./output/${video} --language 0:eng ${video}")
```

The double-quotes tell the shell to treat that whole thing as one long string, so it gets stored as a single element in the array, and therefore passed to `mkvmerge` as a single argument containing spaces, rather than a series of arguments.

Note that `echo` hides the distinction between a space within an argument and a space *between* arguments, making it highly misleading for things like this. Putting `set -x` before the command should clarify what's actually happening. With your example filenames, `set -x` shows what's being run:

```
echo '-o ./output/clip2.mkv --language 0:eng clip2.mkv' '--language 0:ger ./ger/clip2.mka' '--language 0:spa ./spa/clip2.mka'
```

See the long single-quoted sections? That's how it indicates those are long arguments containing spaces, rather than sequences of separate arguments.

To solve it, just use normal quoting when you build the array (i.e. the same quoting you'd use when passing arguments directly to the command). zsh doesn't word-split by default, so technically you don't need to quote at all, but I prefer to follow compatible-with-other-shells quoting style, so I quote all variable expansions:

```
#!/bin/zsh

mkdir -p output

for video in *.mkv
do
    audioargs=(-o "./output/${video}" --language 0:eng "./${video}")
    for audiodir in *(/)
        do
            audioargs+=(--language "0:${audiodir}" "./${audiodir}/${video:r}.mka")
        done
    echo "${audioargs[@]}"
done
```

Which gives this result with `set -x`:

```
echo -o ./output/clip2.mkv --language 0:eng ./clip2.mkv --language 0:ger ./ger/clip2.mka --language 0:spa ./spa/clip2.mka
```